# cygwin node implementation over mapping issues node server across LAN

Tags: node.js, windows, development-environment, web-development-server

I have a Windows box (clean, no bloat, no node, no servers) that I develop with, and incidentally have cygwin on it.  I also have an Arch Linux server fully configured like a dream, the way I like it, and even use putty on the Win box for it.  I would love to use the resources on the Linux for this, however the problem is I spend too much time on nginx, php-fpm and installations like that on the server, to keep a proper dns name dialed in to have proper dns accessible names to map the browser on the dev machine to the server, normally, when I need it.

I'm willing to break the pattern, to stab at a quick solution, since this comes up so often for me, but I want the easy option, I thought I ask opinions.

- What I need is a way to access the Node server, any node server for that matter, from the Win box browsers. That's my main requirement.
- Secondarily, I need to access Git, on the server, for repo storage, and preferable even work on the files out of there as `\\hostname\projects\site\index.js` etc.. on the Win box.
  -I prefer NOT to use Git through any kind of start menu, or icon, I would hate that, I'm a command line user.

### Existing

Win development, want to work on a node app, arch box on 192.168 subnet with working node, no dns mapped (can add to etc/hosts, but to have the Linux box capture that dns name too much work for now)

**Option 1**

Use cygwin right here, install node on it, go to town on development, but I want to use the git repo/git on the Arch Linux box somehow still, I won't install Git, or Node.js on Windows *per se*, only through command line, Choclatey maybe, but preferably cygwin, if there is such a thing, I just haven't used it before really.

**Option 2**

What's available for me to map something easy to the Linux, and use the resources available there and putty, e.g. do I need a quick dns solution or what am I looking for? (Don't suggest bind or dnsmasq please) I much prefer bind, have it on there, but don't want to get that dialed in, just want to spend an hour on this each time I need to work on a website, I need something quick.

What about a proxy, if I point my browsers to proxy to the IP of the server?  I don't really mind using IPs, as long as the site allow it.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with dnsmasq.  Its wayyy simpler than Bind, you just put names in etc/hosts.  For the Windows machine, install Virtual Box and Ubuntu.  Not sure cygwin works at all with Node but it would probably suck compared to Virtual Box.

There is no simple Linux DNS that I know of besides dnsmasq. nsd is not bad but its still a pain in the ass.  There might be an easy to setup Windows DNS server though.  But I would just use Virtual Box and dnsmasq.

On Windows the hosts file is normally in \WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc

Comment: With virtualbox, then are you suggesting remote to a DE(Desktop Environment)?  hmm.  interesting if so, but no DE on that box, don't want one.  And note, i was hesitant for a DNS solution, maybe i didn't make that clear enough.  Any better ideas on option 2, or any other solutions? :-)

Comment: don't know what DE is. If you don't like Virtual Box other comments still apply.

Comment: Edited my answer for DE,s.  Point for the effort, still looking for a better solution, i cant imagine having to run my browser through a remote desktop protocol, as a development norm.  :-|  I do appreciate the option though.

Comment: Virtual Box instead of cygwin on Windows. Not remote. If you want to browse to local name in Windows edit hosts file on Windows. To create name on Linux edit hosts file run dnsmasq. If dnamasq too hard to setup with arch repartition and install Ubuntu.